# Object in html table

Tags: html, powershell, html-table

I want to output the content of a text file to a html table. So far I was able to output the text file by converting each 4 lines into an object. But when it is display in the html table I have something like:

```
TimeCreated                    LevelDisplayNaeme                        ID

TimeCreated: 04/07/14          LevelDisplayName: information            Id: 4
```

I can't find a way to just have:

```
TimeCreated                    LevelDisplayNaeme                        ID

04/07/14                          information                            4
```

My code is:

```
$logs = get-content "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Reports\SourceFile.txt"
$logObject = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $logs.length; $i++)
    {
        if ([regex]::ismatch($logs[$i],"TimeCreated"))
        {
            $logObject = new-object system.Management.Automation.PSObject
            $logObject | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "TimeCreated" -value ($logs[$i])
            #$logObject | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "TimeCreated" -value ($logs[$i]).replace("TimeCreated:  ","")
            $logObject | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "LevelDisplayName" -value ($logs[$i+1]).replace("LevelDisplayName:  ","")
            $logObject | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "ID" -value ($logs[$i+2]).replace("ID:  ","")
            $logObject | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Message" -value ($logs[$i+3]).replace("Message:  ","")
            $logObject | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "BackupSize" -value ($logs[$i+4]).replace("BackupSize (GB):  ","")
            $logObjects += $logObject        

            "<TR>" >> $fileName

            "<TD>" >> $fileName 
            $logObject.TimeCreated>> $fileName 
            "</TD>" >> $fileName

            "<TD>" >> $fileName
            $logObject.LevelDisplayName >> $fileName
            "</TD>" >> $fileName

            "<TD>" >> $fileName
            $logObject.ID >> $fileName
            "</TD>" >> $fileName

            "<TD>" >> $fileName
            $logObject.Message >> $fileName
            "</TD>" >> $fileName

            "<TD>" >> $fileName
            $logObject.BackupSize >> $fileName
            "</TD>" >> $fileName

            "</TR>" >> $fileName  

          }

         "</body>" >> $fileName
        "</html>" >> $fileName

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I created a test file to work with C:\Temp\Test.log, and it contains:

```
TimeCreated:  4/12/2014
LevelDisplayName:  Red
ID:  A1232
Message:  Test Message 1
BackupSize (GB):  16
TimeCreated:  4/13/2014
LevelDisplayName:  Orange
ID:  A1233
Message:  Test Message 2
BackupSize (GB):  17.2
TimeCreated:  4/14/2014
LevelDisplayName:  Blue
ID:  A1234
Message:  Test Message 3
BackupSize (GB):  18.4
```

I am assuming that is something like what your input file looks like. From there I ran this script:

```
$logs = get-content "C:\Temp\test.log"
$logObjects = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $logs.length; $i++)
    {
        if ([regex]::ismatch($logs[$i],"TimeCreated"))
        {
            $logObject = new-object PSObject -Property @{
            "TimeCreated" = ($logs[$i])  -replace ".+:\s+?","";
            "LevelDisplayName" = ($logs[$i+1]) -replace ".+:\s+?","";
            "ID" = ($logs[$i+2]) -replace ".+:\s+?","";
            "Message" = ($logs[$i+3]) -replace ".+:\s+?","";
            "BackupSize" = ($logs[$i+4]) -replace ".+:\s+?",""
            }
            $logObjects += $logObject
        }
    }
$logObjects|select TimeCreated,LevelDisplayName,ID,Message,BackupSize|convertto-html|Out-File c:\temp\test.html -Force
```

The HTML file that it outputs looks like this:

```
TimeCreated LevelDisplayName    ID      Message             BackupSize
4/12/2014   Red                 A1232   Test Message 1      16 
4/13/2014   Orange              A1233   Test Message 2      17.2 
4/14/2014   Blue                A1234   Test Message 3      18.4
```

Comment: This is exactly what the input looks like but it's a text file. So I save my file as *.log but nothing seems to change. Is there something different between a log input and a text input?

Comment: Nope, no difference at all. The difference is that you are manually creating HTML, and I use the `ConvertTo-HTML` cmdlet, paired with `Out-File`.

Comment: I can't manage to get the same output as yours. My intput is:       

TimeCreated      : 03/04/2014 07:57:32
LevelDisplayName : Information
Id               : 50067
Message          : DHCP a reçu un identificateur SSID (Service Set Identifier) Livebox-816F pour la carte réseau dont l’adresse réseau est 0x0
BackupSize (GB)  : 0,00

Comment: I updated the replace method to a regex version so that should work better for you. Try it with the updated script.